# Adding custom setting in plyr

Tags: javascript, html, plyr

I'd like to add a custom option to the settings that will set a variable value

For the sake of the argument, let's say it's `theme,` with the options: `light`, `dark` and `blue`

It will open up the regular settings options with Theme listed and 'Light' as the default value

When the options are opened it shows

Light

Dark

Blue

with the back button.

Then when one of the buttons are clicked, there is an event where I set the variable value, let's say `themeValue='dark'`

I thought this would be simple to do but can't find any documentation or working examples. Is this possible/documented anywhere? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add new button to menu like this: `document.querySelector('[role="menu"]');` - this should select your `settings menu` and then add your `theme button` to it?